# Combining gulp-inject and gulp-coffee

Tags: gulp, gulp-inject

I would like to compile my coffee files and inject them into my index.html by utilizing gulp streams.

This is what I tried:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.coffee.source)
    .pipe(coffee())
    .pipe(inject(paths.index.source))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.coffee.destination));
});
```

and this is the error:

```
[17:57:39] 'scripts' errored after 2.19 ms passing target file as a string is deprecated! Pass a vinyl file stream (i.e. use `gulp.src`)!
```

Apparently what I was doing is deprecated. Is it possible to do that in one stream?

Comment: Did you have to define paths.coffee.destination manually for each source? or is it something that is done automatically? i'm trying to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You should provide inject with vinyl file stream, exactly what error says, i.e. (as in documentation:https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject#injecting-files-relative-to-target-files):

```
var inject = require('gulp-inject');

gulp.src('./src/**/*.html')
  .pipe(inject(gulp.src('./src/**/*.js', {read: false}), {relative: true}))
  .pipe('./src');
```

or in your code, you should change

```
inject(paths.index.source)
```

to

```
inject(gulp.src(paths.index.source, {read: false}), {relative: true}))
```